# Logical Architecture Diagram

Tags: architecture, visio, staruml

I know this is quite a generic question which a normal google search result should give but some of how i am not convinced from results . 
My understanding of logical architecture diagram is that it is logical grouping of all components that make an app work ( including software/hardware ) is this Right ? If I am wrong then what is logical architecture diagram ? Can anyone point me to logical architecture diagram of a Web Application .

If i want to use StarUml for this diagram is this right tool for this diagram ? any pointers to this ? I dont see option for logical architecture diagram.

Answer (score 3):

**First** :

Forget  anything about UML or any  tool about UML. You are an engineer not a painter.

**Then:**

Ask yourself : Why I need to draw "Logical architecture diagram"  of "my" web application? How It will help "me"?

**Know your lingo :** What is "Logical Architecture" ..

> Logical architecture: the large-scale organization of software classes
>   into packages, subsystems, and layers. “Logical” because no decisions
>   about how these elements are deployed across different operating
>   system processes or across physical computers in a network [ **Check Larman's Book , Applying UML and Patterns**]

**Finally :**
If you have valid reason to draw your "Logical Architecture", draw it using simple boxes,arches etc... Create your own notation at first...  :-)

**Yeaaa...You want UML  OK**

Then you will use UML package diagrams and class diagrams to show of major elements of your software and their dependencies...But How?

Check [Lecture That UseLarman's Book](http://csis.pace.edu/~marchese/CS616/Lec11/se_l11.htm) from this link...Or Read Larman's Book Chapter ....It will give a clear view...

**Can You Draw It With Star UML?**

You can draw UML Logical Architecture Diagrams with your hands on paper or with Start UML...Since you will just draw package, class , interface and dependencies...

Just open a new class diagram in Start UML , put package and class and interface and dependency relationship elements which shows your "Logical Architecture" That is all...

**Recomendation :**

Check http://www.codingthearchitecture.com/  [ Simon Brown ]... He has some video lectures free on youtube or vimeo which is worth to watch them...

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your definition corresponds to Component diagram defined in UML. There is a more specific definition for Logical Architecture Diagram [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19528-01/820-2195/gezkd/index.html), suitable for modeling of tiered architectures such as web applications. I hope it's helpful.

Comment: Thanks but if you look at liferay architeure diagram it's different [check here](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Logical+Architecture) is it becuse it is not web app but it is server

Comment: You can think about Logical architecture, as a logical structure of the system, which address functional and non-functional requirements. Depending on the purposes and usage of the system different architectural solutions are more appropriate. You can read Chpter 6 in [link](http://www.amazon.com/Software-Engineering-9th-Edition-Sommerville/dp/0137035152).
It doesn't really matter what kind of tool you are using, you can use simple boxes and arrows, to represent the elements and their relations.

Comment: Thanks for all details but I dont find boxes in Star Uml or VIsio any specific Pointers we will be helpful